# nginx redirects - how can I optimise my code?

Tags: nginx

I've got the following config (which works) in nginx:

```
location /de-de/sitemap.xml {
    try_files $uri /sitemaps/de-de/sitemap.xml;
}

location /en-ae/sitemap.xml {
    try_files $uri /sitemaps/en-ae/sitemap.xml;
}

location /en-de/sitemap.xml {
    try_files $uri /sitemaps/en-de/sitemap.xml;
}

location /en-gb/sitemap.xml {
    try_files $uri /sitemaps/en-gb/sitemap.xml;
}

location /en-us/sitemap.xml {
    try_files $uri /sitemaps/en-us/sitemap.xml;
}
```

This is because requests from the outside will be looking for (say) `/en-gb/sitemap.xml`, but the actual file for said sitemap actually exists in `/sitemaps/en-gb/sitemap.xml`.

Now, like I said before, this works, but I can't help but think it could be optimised (i.e using some type of matching rule, rather than listing each of the store codes individually??) but I've not had much luck making it work.

Plus I'm not sure if the `try_files` command is the best for this purpose.

Thank you.

PS, it is only the `sitemap.xml` files that I want to target, all other files that exist within that path should be served as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a back reference to the language element of the path:

```
location ~ "^/([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})/sitemap.xml$" {
    try_files $uri /sitemaps/$1/sitemap.xml;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting a syntax error when I try restarting nginx: `nginx: [emerg] pcre_compile() failed: missing ) in "^/([a-z]" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.com.conf:23`

Comment: Sorry I only tested with `egrep`. For some reason nginx doesn't like the `{2}`. I've edited my answer and the regex now passes configtest on my server.

Comment: You had to put regexp to quotes

Comment: quoted from nginx doc `If a regular expression includes the “}” or “;” characters, the whole expressions should be enclosed in single or double quotes.`, just an FYI